# Specific situations where we should not or cannot type cast instead of "type promotion" when using Flutter/Dart

Tags: flutter, dart

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2Cl0C-9dK48&list=PLjxrf2q8roU1fRV40Ec8200rX6OuQkmnl&index=1

The video above explains Dart's Type promotion. There is no doubt about the content of the explanation itself.

As a premise of the explanation, the explanation is expanded as "when type casting is not performed".

I'm wondering if we can't use "type cast".

Because, I can't imagine "a situation where we can't typecast while developing an app with Flutter".

So, could you give me a concrete example of "a situation where we can't cast a type, or a situation where we shouldn't cast a type"?

Or is there a situation where we shouldn't typecast in Dart programming other than Flutter?

Comment: [Casting will result in a runtime error if it fails](https://dart.dev/guides/language/type-system#what-is-soundness). For example, a cast such as `'hello' as int` could crash your program if the error is not caught. Type promotion doesn't come with any risk of a runtime error/exception.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Certainly, that is an important point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mmcdon20 commented, there is a possibility of a run-time error when type casting, so processing for error handling is required.